# Data wrangling - data spread over three rows - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, dataset

I have a **very** untidy data set something like this

```
A tibble: 200000 x 2
ChatData  
 <chr>                  
 1 Sep 30, 2018 7:12pm       
 2 Person A
 3 Hello                        
 4 Sep 30, 2018 7:11pm        
 5 Person B           
 6 Hello there                 
 7 Sep 30, 2018 7:10pm        
 8 Person A
...
```

As you can see it goes date, person name, comment, and repeats.

I am working on the problem and have a very complex method that adds a score column depending on the names etc....

I would like to transform this into something like this

```
Person A , Person B
Hello      NA
NA         Hello there
how's you, NA
...
```

(The date as a row name or third column would be great but not essential to the question)

Optimally I am looking for a dplyr/tidyverse solution
I am working with lots of data so no slow for loops etc..

Raw data to work with:

```
structure(list(ChatData = c("Sep 30, 2018 7:12pm", "Person A", "Hello", "Sep 30, 2018 7:11pm", "Person B", "Hello there")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

If anyone is wondering I am analysing facebook messenger data, and this is the form it comes in when you download it.

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide the output of `dput(head(ChatData, 20))`?

Comment: @Ryan Added, thank you for the suggestion, didn't know about dput(), thank you, I haven't done 20 as I have to change them all to make anon. If its needed I will, may take some time.

Comment: do you have only 1 feature?

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara What do you mean by feature?

Comment: there is only 1 column which is called `ChatData`. Are you sure about the structure?

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara I am sure that there is just one column containing all this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, your starting data set has only one column (aka feature). But in this case, there are three types of data that are encoded here about each message: a timestamp, the label of the person, and a message. It will be more useful to transform these into a table where each message is in its own row, and each column represents a different aspect of each observation, i.e. in long, or "tidy", format:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html

In the approach below, the user first defines what features are repeated in the data set. I call them "headers" here, since I'm working toward a table where these are the column headers. Then the script adds that information to the data and converts the single-column data into a tidy format with one row per message, and one aspect of each message in each column.

Your requested output is a minor variation of this, addressed in the last line below: `%>% spread(person, msg)`, which separates out the Person A and Person b data into separate columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

header_names <- c("timestamp", "person", "msg")

rows_per <- length(header_names)
data_length <- length(data$ChatData) / rows_per
data2 <- data %>%
  mutate(msg_number = rep(1:(nrow(data)/rows_per), each=rows_per),
         # This line repeats the header_names sequence for each msg
         header = rep(header_names, data_length)) %>%
  spread(header, ChatData) %>%
  mutate(timestamp = lubridate::mdy_hm(timestamp)) %>%
  spread(person, msg)


head(data2)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  msg_number timestamp           `Person A` `Person B` 
       <int> <dttm>              <chr>      <chr>      
1          1 2018-09-30 19:12:00 Hello      NA         
2          2 2018-09-30 19:11:00 NA         Hello there
```

Comment: Could you explain the headers variable please?

Comment: Added more explanation to answer. Does that help?

Comment: Nice answer! One small correction: I think where you have `rows_per <- length(headers)` it should be `rows_per <- length(header_names)` to match the variable name you declared in the previous line.

Comment: @krads Thank you, think this is what was confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

#### As you basically just have a character vector that you would like to convert into a 3 columnn data.frame

One other option is to simply use `matrix` and specify `ncol=3` and `byrow=TRUE`

```
# your sample data
d <- structure(list(ChatData = c("Sep 30, 2018 7:12pm", "Person A", "Hello", "Sep 30, 2018 7:11pm", "Person B", "Hello there")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

matrix( d$ChatData, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE,
        dimnames=list( NULL, c("date_time", "person", "message")) )
```

Result is a character matrix:

```
     date_time             person     message      
[1,] "Sep 30, 2018 7:12pm" "Person A" "Hello"      
[2,] "Sep 30, 2018 7:11pm" "Person B" "Hello there"
```

But you can wrap that in `as.data.frame()` to convert to a data.frame and continue working from there with `dplyr` if that's what you want.

#### Put it together for a whole solution:

It becomes a nice short, readable bit of code IMO:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

result_df <- 
  matrix( d$ChatData, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE, 
          dimnames=list(NULL, c("date_time", "person", "message")) ) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(date_time=lubridate::mdy_hm(date_time))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
data %>% group_by(msg_number = rep(1:(nrow(data)/3), each=3)) %>% 
  summarize(msg_data = list(ChatData)) %>% as.data.frame

  msg_number                                   msg_data
1          1       Sep 30, 2018 7:12pm, Person A, Hello
2          2 Sep 30, 2018 7:11pm, Person B, Hello there
```

This numbers each message and puts the data into a column list.